# Host Blazor WASM in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am trying to host my Blazor WASM application on my S3 bucket under a sub path, but I can't really get it to work like I would expect it to.

In order to get it to work, I had to make some changes which I would've preferred not needing to make, especially since they break the application on my development build, so I always have to change between the 2 when I publish / want to develop

In my application I have 2 pages, lets say page1 and page2. On application startup, I want to see page 1. this page has the @page "/" on top. The other page has @page ="/page2". These same paths are then found in my NavMenu.razor.

Now locally I don't care for sub paths, so I'm fine with the application being hosted at localhost:port/ which would go to page 1, and localhost:port/page2 which would go to page 2. In order to get it working in my S3 bucket however, where my application is hosted under s3Url/subpath/{published files}, I had to make some changes: in my index.html I put the

I find myself unable to make all of these changes through appsettings or environment, which makes it time consuming, and error prone to accidentally make errors and push the wrong settings to my s3 bucket when i publish.

Is there any way to handle a sub path better? In the documentation I found this the following  [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#app-base-path) where they talk about this exact issue, and they say it can be fixed by running it locally using this command:

```
dotnet run --pathbase=/{RELATIVE URL PATH (no trailing slash)}
```

but even if I do that, since I had to edit all page names and nav links it still doesn't work.

I feel like there must be a better way for me to handle this, so that it works on both development and also on publish, without having to make additional code changes whenever I publish, and then undoing them again when I want to develop locally.